# make hover effect on one element without class

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have many .PlaceViewIcon div include same image , the problem is when i hover on only one div, the rest of div`s change the src also . i want the only div that i hover to change not all div`s . without put id on every element . i think the problem can solve with ( this ) i tried to read about it , but not understand how it working

this is my jquery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".PlaceViewIcon").mouseover(function() { 
           $('img').attr("src", "../../../prototype/img/plan-view-hover.png");
           });
 $(".PlaceViewIcon").mouseout(function() {
           $('img').attr("src", "../../../prototype/img/plan-view.png");
          });

});
```

The HTML :

```
<div class="span2" >
                  <p  class="PlaceViewIcon">
                   <a href="#"><img src="../../../prototype/img/plan-view.png" width="25" height="20" /></a></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: you need to target teh relative image.... please share the html sample

Comment: try `$(this).find('img').attr("src", ...`, it the image is within the hovered div

Comment: @ArunPJohny , its works now :D thanks i know that i should use  ( this ) . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you edit all the images of your html content. If you want to edit only the images that are inside this div, you should do :

```
 $(this).find('img').attr("src", "../../../prototype/img/plan-view.png");
```

So, in the div, it will find an img attribute and it will edit his source. 
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `$(this)` like:

```
$(".PlaceViewIcon").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
      ...
    }).mouseout(function(){
      ...
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/7RH3j/

But I am wondering if you could solve this issue with the pseudo css hover:

```
.PlaceViewIcon :hover
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to find element using xpath

with jquery it might be look like this

1st create xpath function

```
function getXPath( element )
{
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
    var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}
```

2nd create hover function

```
var xp;

$('.tags').mouseover(function() {
    xp = getXpath(this);
});
```

3rd lookup by xpath

```
var elementLookedupXPath = $(xml).find(xp);
```